# Joda-time parser with instance-local default timezone

Tags: scala, jodatime

Is there an "instance-local" version of Joda's DateTimeZone.setDefault? I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```scala
val parser = new ParserWithDefaultTimezone("GMT+1");
parser.parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00").getMillis // -3600000L
parser.parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC").getMillis // 0L
```

Without polluting anything global. All I can find in the Joda docs is something that (ironically) modifies global state.

If there is a non-Joda solution, I am interested in that, too.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that if there is no ready-to-use class that does this, I'll settle for: "what is the easiest way to see if a time string contains an explicit timezone?" I can't distinguish between an explicit one and a timezone that Joda set by default.

EDIT 2: I don't have a format string to feed; I'm looking for something that infers the format at runtime.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? There are several new classes in Java 8 that you could leverage

Comment: Java 8. Are there classes that can tell if a string without explicit format contains a timezone or not? From what I understand of the (impenetrable) documentation it's all based on explicit format strings, no?

Comment: The string `"1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"` has an explicit format for the time zone. If your `String` contains a correctly formatted `ZoneId` then you could parse it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`withZone`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) to alter the date/time zone used:

```
val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"))
val date = fmt.parseDateTime(???);
```

The set-up required to make the time zone optional is a little bit more complicated:

```
val tz = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendLiteral(" ").appendTimeZoneId().toFormatter()
val fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
            .appendOptional(tz.getParser())
            .toFormatter().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"))

println(fmt.parseDateTime("1970-01-01 12:00:00 UTC"))
println(fmt.parseDateTime("1970-01-01 12:00:00 Europe/Berlin"))
println(fmt.parseDateTime("1970-01-01 12:00:00"))
```

As long as your remark

> I don't have a format string to feed; I'm looking for something that infers the format at runtime.

applies only with respect to the time zone, solution 2 might do what you want. If, on the other hand, you really don't know, in wich format the dates are provided (`dd/mm/yyyy` vs. `mm/dd/yyyy` vs. `yyyy/mm/dd` vs. whatever), then I think you are out of luck: such a conversion would be ambiguous at best. Is `01/03/2015` the 1st of March or the 3rd of January?